# Initializing singleton in class instead of instance?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

Why can you not do the following?

```
class foo {
  private static foo instance  = new foo();
  List <string> messages = new List<string>();


  private foo(){}
  public static void doSomething(){..}

}
```

Edit:

I mean is there a difference between doing this:

```
class foo {
  private static foo instance  = new foo();
  List <string> messages = new List<string>();


  private foo(){}
  public static void doSomething(){..}

}
```

or

```
class foo {
  private static foo instance;
  List <string> messages = new List<string>();


  private foo(){}
  public static void doSomething(){..}

  public foo getInstance(){
    if(instance!=null){
       return instance;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What can't you do? Apart from a missing return type in `doSomething` all is fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the non-lazy method of implementing the Singleton pattern for languages that support it. It's perfectly acceptable to do this, especially since it's one of the ways of implementing a thread-safe Singleton. However, if your Singleton object is expensive (see [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)) to create, then it might not be appropriate to create it in this manner.

If your code doesn't compile, as the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479636/572) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479652/572) point out, your syntax for the `doSomething` method is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `doSomething()` is missing a return type.  Try:

```
class Foo {
    private static Foo instance = new Foo();
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();

    private Foo() { }

    public static void doSomething() {
        // Make any necessary accesses to "instance" here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, you just didn't give a return type to `doSomething()`.